# How can I populate my list with data being stored in a sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, xamarin

I am currently working on a Xamarin forms app. The idea is to get data from an API and users will be able to view recipes, add it to favorites and search.

I ran into a bit of a problem with displaying my list of favorited items items . I am unable to view my data into my list, Not sure If I am even inserting into the table properly.  I will try to post relevant code as much as I can. I would appreciate any help :)

Here I am clicking the add to fave button - DBManager.cs

```
     public void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        //add to favoritelist
        dbModel.insertNewToDo(temp);


    }
```

Here is the insertNewToDo function DBManager.cs

```
private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
    private ObservableCollection<Pancake>temp;
    public DBManager()
    {
        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();

    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Pancake>> CreateTable()
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Pancake>();
        //get
        var pancake = await _connection.Table<Pancake>().ToListAsync();
        var allTasks = new ObservableCollection<Pancake>(pancake);
        
        return allTasks;
    }
```

Here is favorite page is supposed display list of pancakes but doesn't :/ :(((
FavePage.xaml.cs

```
ObservableCollection<Pancake> allPancakes;
public FavePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();



}
 





protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    
    allPancakes = await dbModel.CreateTable();             
    allFaveTable.ItemsSource = allPancakes;
    base.OnAppearing();

}
```

Here is FavePage.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        
        <Button Text="Delete"  />
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="allFaveTable">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that in 'allPancakes' collection are some items ?

Comment: you did not post `insertNewToDo`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't bound the ItemsSource of the ListView to the observable collection. Make the ObservableCollection into a public property of the page that contains the StackLayout, and use x:Bind in the ListView to bind the ListView's ItemsSource  to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: He dont need to bind the collection because he is already set ItemsSource in OnAppearing.